# Library header not found if CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR is set with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, header, static-libraries, restkit, xcodebuild

My iOS project uses RestKit as a static library (in a GIT submodule).

When I do:

```
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug
```

Everything goes well. However, when I change the output directory with:

```
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=build
```

xcodebuild can't find my library header file:

```
/path/to/my/project/file.m:9:9: fatal error: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

What happens here ?

---

### Edit

After some investigations, I found out that when adding `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=build`, xcodebuild doesn't copy headers from RestKit at all.

Without using `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`:

```
CpHeader Code/RestKit.h ...
```

Using `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`: nothing.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://devforums.apple.com/message/713022. A bug report has been submitted to Apple, more info on the thread above.

Comment: I am experiencing this problem too. Would be nice if this question wasn't needlessly flagged as "Too Localized." This question certainly helps this future visitor. Thanks Kev. The header files folders configured in the packaging build settings of an XCode project don't seem to be used by xcodebuild on the command line. Is there a command we are missing that does this?

Comment: Here is a thread with potential solutions... Have to post it in the comments since this question was needlessly "closed as too localized." - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restkit/rlvxip8UGz4

Comment: Could you try to put an absolute path for `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` ? This solved my problem. I asked the thread to be closed as it is obviously a bug (or at least a documentation issue). If my solution helps, I'll reopen it and answer with both our solutions.

Comment: Why was this thread closed?